# Issue with Chrome jumping to bottom on reload on my website

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, scroll, scrollbar

I hope someone can help me figure out this issue because I'm at a loss.

In one of my sites, it seems there is an issue when pages are reloaded.

Sometimes (not all the time, just sometimes, which makes it even weirder), when I refresh the page, the page will jump to bottom for a second, and then it will jump back up to the position you were in.

Here's an example: https://www.gamesatlas.com/cod-modern-warfare/guides/all-operators-in-call-of-duty-modern-warfare-full-list-of-characters-for-coalition-and-allegiance-factions

Go about halfway through the page. Then refresh. Keep refreshing the page. At one point you will see that Chrome will jump to the footer, and then jump back up to the position you were in. And this will keep happening on subsequent refreshes.

If it doesn't happen with this page, you can try ANY page of the website, same thing.

Can you reproduce it? And if so, does anyone have any clue on why this is happening? It's making me pull my hair out.

The weirder part is that this happens only one of my sites, despite having other sites that are set up pretty much identically (same exact code), yet it doesn't happen there.

So I'm really at a loss. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Check for focus, scroll or any other events like that which change the screen position.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did check and there don't seem to be any. Plus, the position where it jumps to, it's different everytime. It seems like it shifts down of a certain amount of pixels depending on your original position, then goes back up. :(

Comment: I know this is old. I have the same issue. The only thing im came up it's to a hard-code common container height. In my case the issue was produced when user go back with browser button.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this, it seemed to be caused by a Chrome extension that I had logged out of (in this case, boomerang).  When I removed the extension, the problem seemed to go away. It was driving my crazy too.